# Compute the fundamental matrix solution for a given system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Consider the system:
>   $$\left \{\begin{align}\dot x &= x-y-x(x^2+y^2)\\
> \dot y &= x+y-y(x^2+y^2) \end{align}\right.$$
>   Find the fundamental matrix solution $Y(t)$ explicitly, assuming $x(0) = \cos \phi_0, y(0) = \sin \phi_0$.

I know the system can be written as:

$$\left \{\begin{align}\dot r &= r-r^3\\
\dot \phi &= 1 \end{align}\right.$$

Whereas I'm looking for $Y(t)$ such that: $\dot Y(t) = Df(x) \cdot Y(t)$ (and $Y(0) = I$. I guess I should use the system in polar coördinates then:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\dot y_{11}(t) & \dot y_{12}(t) \\ \dot y_{21}(t) & \dot y_{22}(t)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1-3r(t)^2 & 0\\ 0  & 0\end{pmatrix}  \cdot \begin{pmatrix}y_{11}(t) & y_{12}(t) \\ y_{21}(t) & y_{22}(t)\end{pmatrix}  $$

Then I should solve $\dot y_{11}(t) = (1-3r(t)^2)\cdot y_{11}(t)$ but how can I do this?

Or should I use the original system, where the Jacobian matrix seems complicated?

Comment: The equation is $dr/dt=(1-3r^2)r$, and that can be solved by separation of variables. By the way, isn't the “fundamental matrix solution” something which is relevant for *linear* systems only?

Answer (score 1):

After solving $r'=r-r^3$ you will have $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$.

This will give you $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ as functions of $t$ and of the initial condition $(x(0),y(0))=(x_0,y_0)$. The best way to proceed is to write down the solutions in the form
$$
(x(t),y(t))=\varphi_i(x_0,y_0),
$$
since then $Y(t)$ is simply the Jacobian $d_{(\cos\phi_0,\sin\phi_0)}\varphi_t$.

PS: One should note that it is not fine to talk about fundamental matrices of nonlinear systems, although of course there is only one reasonable interpretation of your question.